# Is it possible to use a modifier from a different contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, modifiers

Is there a way to use modifiers from a different contract? My attempt did not work.

```
contract con1{

    modifier supermod(uint _value){
        require(_value == 1);
        _;
    }
}

contract con2{

    con1 public contract1;

    function setCon1Address(address _address)public{
        contract1 = con1(_address);
    }

    function test() contract1.supermod(uint _value){
        ..stuff..
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifiers have a similar scope to internal functions. The only way to access `supermod` from `con2` is if `con2` inherits from `con1`

Answer (score 1):

Change to inheritance.

`contract con2 is con1 {`

I removed the parts you don't need and fiddled with the function to grab the input for the modifier.

```
contract con1{

    modifier supermod(uint _value){
        require(_value == 1);
        _;
    }
}

contract con2 is con1 {

    function test(uint value) supermod(value){
        // this will happen if value == 1
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem here is that i want to use a modifier from a contract that already exist. if i use inheritance i create a new con1 from my understanding. But thanks for the help.

Comment: Different question. Then, no. Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to use another modifier is inherit that contract

> Modifiers are inheritable properties of contracts and may be overridden by derived contracts, but only if they are marked virtual. [More info](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/contracts.html#function-modifiers)